# PHP Multi URL Redirector with Array

Tags: php, redirect

Im trying to create a php to redirect multiple urls with an specific ID for example

```
mysite.com/url.php?id=1
id=1  will automatically redirect to www.google.com
mysite.com/url.php?id=2
id = 2  will automatically redirect to www.bing.com
successively ...
```

I think that an array can simplify it

i will apreciate your answers.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a static array, then use the following code:

```
<?php
    $sites = array(
        1 => 'http://domain.tld';
        2 => 'http://anotherdomain.tld';
    );

    if (isset($_GET['id']) && array_key_exists($_GET['id']), $sites) {
        header('location: ' . $sites[$_GET['id']]);
    } else {
        // 404?
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php


    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

    $id = (int)(trim($id));


    switch($id){
        case 1:
            header("Location: http://www.google.com/");exit;
            break;

        case 2:
            header("Location: http://www.bing.com/");exit;
            break;

        default:
            header("Location: http://www.default.com/");exit;
            break;
    }

?>
```